# Designing genomic search strategies for non-coding RNAs using BLAST

Tags: dataset, experiment-design, exploratory-data-analysis

I am interested in developing a computational search of some types of non-coding RNAs (ncRNAs) on a new genome. I have some questions related to the nature of my experiment, because it is an exploratory study, and I can generate different results by applying different BLAST search strategies. The final output consists of different counts of each type of ncRNA for each BLAST strategy.

How I can design good search strategies, taking into account that it is the first search on this new genome?

References will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a little more focused, but it still needs to be more specific. Can you give more details on what kind of ncRNAs you are searching with, and what the objective of the search is. Is it to identify putative ncRNAs on a new genome? I have previously been doing similar things $-$ here is one [reference](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/pdfplus/10.1089/cmb.2008.0180).

Comment: See also this [reference](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/pdf/10.1089/dna.2006.0551).

Comment: @NRH : I am very happy for your answers and references. The types of ncRNAs are those annotated in [Ensembl](http://www.ensembl.org/) database: snRNAs, snoRNAs, misc_RNAs, rRNAs and miRNAs; for homology searches. The objetive is identify putative ncRNAs in a Tunicate genome, not only by homology approaches, also by structural alignments. We hope report a in silico list of candidates to the different types of ncRNAs families, that may be classified based on [Rfam] annotation. Also, I want to use 4 different Blast strategies, suggested to search ncRNAs, for the homology stage.